# Identify a non-Lego Santa set

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands

[image: Santa blocks]

Yeah so basically I tried the usual sites, but even putting in “North Pole sign” came up with nothing except one kinda similar. I can’t find anything on this set. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I could not find anything for 'Santa's letters' and the parts with 'North Pole' where showing different stickers on [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/),

Based on the design of the bricks and the strange colour used for the characters I strongly suspect these are not LEGO bricks.

The 2x2 slope for example does not show a visible LEGO logo on the studs and each stud is quite different. The bags they are packaged in are also not standard.

[image]

It will be quite difficult to identify this set if you cannot find a box, instructions or some other markings/part numbers. Clone-brands rarely have an online set database where you can find sets or an official website.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find anything in a Google search for *compatible +"santa's letters" building construction* - this appears to be a product that hasn't made an impact on the Internet.